# Generate all possible correct sentences from a set of words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, generator

I have a set of **276** different words, I want to generate all possible correct sentences from them. It can be composed of two words only or more.

I used **NLTK** tagger to give every word a class. For instance, ('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN') but this technique has drowbacks when the words are independent from each other (An array of 276 words in my case).

If anyone has an idea of how I could do it, it would really help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need a *grammar* to describe valid combinations of word classes or words. For example:

```
S -> NP VP
NP -> det adj* noun
VP -> verb NP
VP -> verb NP conj NP
```

and so on. This is a fairly old and simple mechanism, but should be easy enough to implement. You simply generate expansions of the rules until you hit word class categories, and then substitute the respective words for them. The meaning is, of course, a different issue, as your sentences will be grammatically correct, but semantically weird.

Comment: The problem is that when I try to get the words classes using nltk.tag.pos_tag() function, the results are mostly inaccurate since the words are independant

Comment: Then don't use it. If you only have 276 words, assign them manually to the correct class. Note, though, that some words can have multiple classes: _light_ is an adjective, verb, and a noun, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put correct grammar rules for making the correct required sentence.

For more info you can go through the following link:

https://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Comment: Is there anyway to get all possible tags for a word ? as mentionned Oliver Manson  light is an adjective, verb, and a noun.

Comment: It actually depends on the way you use the word and the grammar you have mentioned. Suppose we have following sentences:- this box is light. then this sentence will follow different grammar like {noun adj} as here light is an adjective. Now take another sentence like: light is on . So here grammar is {noun det verb} as here light is a noun. So based on the grammar rules you have put and also the way the sentence is made a word will be classified into its tag.